# determine whether $(1,-2,-3)$ is in the span of $(1, 1, 0)$ and $(0 , 1, 1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I think i have some idea on how to approach this, but I need to make sure that i am taking the right steps.

step 1: $(1, -2, -3) = x(1,1,0) + y(0,1,1)$

step 2: $x = 1$ , $x + y = -2$, $y = -3$

since there are solution to the system of equations in step 2, then I have proven that the vector is in the span shown in the original problem.

Is this the correct way of doing this? Have I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: That's absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

What you did is totally correct and, in general, it's the best way of solving this type of problems.

However, in this specific case you could have exploited the presence of $0$'s in $(1,1,0)$ and in $(0,1,1)$. If a vector $(a,b,c)$ is a linear combination of them, that is, if you can write $(a,b,c)$ as $x(1,1,0)+y(0,1,1)$, then $x$ can *only* be $a$ (since the first coordinate of $y(0,1,1)$ is $0$) and $y$ can *only* be $c$. Say, all that remains to be checked is if $x+y$ is equal to $b$ or not.